# Wso2 and jdeveloper (uddi version 2)

Tags: wso2, jdeveloper

We are trying to use WSO2 with jdeveloper, but jdeveloper seems to only support UDDI version2.

Does WSO2 support UDDI version 2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, newer versions have been designed to support both versions 2 as well as 3 of the UDDI specification.

Thanks,
Senaka.